# How to correctly connect command-line VLC to iTunes and Spotify?

Tags: command-line, vlc

When I play an audio file using vlc from comman-line, it always issues warnings

```
/usr/local/bin/vlc ~/file.ogg
VLC media player 3.0.16 Vetinari (revision 3.0.16-0-g5e70837d8d)
[00007f86dee04260] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
2021-09-17 13:59:36.397 VLC[334:9160353] Can't find app with identifier com.apple.iTunes
2021-09-17 13:59:37.009 VLC[334:9160353] Can't find app with identifier com.spotify.client
...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've finally figured out that these warnings can be suppressed by selecting the option

Settings > Interface > Playback behavior > Control external players: Do Nothing

The default is 'Pause Apple Music/Spotify' and the warnings make sense if the two are not installed or properly configured. I don't use them so 'do nothing' is sufficient.